# Finding where a function is not differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function
>   $$f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> (x-1)\min(x,x^2)&\text{if $x\geq 0$,}\\
> x\min\left(x,\dfrac{1}{x}\right)&\text{if $x< 0$.}
> \end{cases}$$
>   Choose the correct option:
>
> a) $f$ is differentiable everywhere;
>
> b) $f$ is not differentiable at one point;
>
> c) $f$ is not differentiable at 3 points;
>
> d) $f$ is not differentiable at two points.

I am getting one point $0$, 
by considering left and right derivative from $0$ to $1$ and $-1$ to $0$.

Please help.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is partially correct. Notice that
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
(x-1)x&\text{if $1\leq x$,}\\
(x-1)x^2&\text{if $0\leq x<1$,}\\
1&\text{if $ -1\leq x<0$,}\\
x^2&\text{if $x< -1$.}
\end{cases}$$
Since the components are polynomials, you should consider the points where the piecewise-function $f$
switches from one piece to another, that is $-1$, $0$ and $1$.

Is $f$ continuous at $0$? What about the differentiability of $f$ at $x=-1$ and at $x=1$?

Comment: A graph can help a lot for intuition as well: https://i.imgur.com/1bHOL3t.png.

Comment: It is not differentiable at 0

Comment: And non differentiable at -1

Comment: It is not continuous at $0$ and therefore it is not differentiable there. What about the differentiability at $x=-1$ and $x=1$?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: And at 1 also non differentiable

Comment: Are you sure? What is the left and right derivative of $f$ at $x=1$?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
(x-1)\min(x,x^2)&\text{if $x\geq 0$,}\\
x\min(x,1/x)&\text{if $x< 0$.}
\end{cases}\\ =\begin{cases}
(x-1)x&\text{if $x\geq 1$,}\\
(x-1)x^2 &\text{if $0\le x\leq 1$,}\\
x^2&\text{if $x< -1$.}\\
1&\text{if $-1\le x< 0$.}\end{cases}$$

and f is not continuous at $x=0$ then not differentiable

Comment: @RobertZ yes sure thanks